# What lua metamethod is being called here?

Tags: lua

I was doing some anti metamethod hooks and I was curious on what metamethod is called in the code below between the parentheses

```lua
local test = "random string"

if (test == "random string") then --// What metamethod if any is being called here?
   print("equals")
end
```

I've done some research and took a look at the __eq metamethod, but that is only called when comparing two tables which isn't what I'm tryna do.

If there isn't any metamethod being called then how would I protect the if condition?

-- Update --

What if I put every string inside of a table for example:

```
local _Table1 = {"Test1", "Test2"}
local _Table2 = {"Test1", "Test2"}

for Index, Value in next, _Table1 do
   if Value == _Table2[Index] then
      print("Tables Match!")
   elseif Value ~= _Table2[Index]
      print("Tables Don't Match!")
   end
end
```

I'm not doing any string converting here, but I'm showing what I could try and do for a simple anti tamper.

Comment: Protect from what?

Comment: I guess then the answer is that it is not possible; if an "attacker" has full access to your code (e.g. it runs on their machine), they will always be able to tamper with it.

Comment: If the code is obfuscated wouldn't that add some difficulty?
They cannot modify code that they cannot read.

Answer (score 0):

The only operator in the parenthesized expression is `==`. Thus the only metamethod in question is `__eq`. The Lua Reference Manual states the following on `__eq`:

> `__eq`: the equal (`==`) operation. Behavior similar to the addition operation, except that **Lua will try a metamethod only when the values being compared are either both tables or both full userdata and they are not primitively equal.**

Your values are strings and thus no metamethod will be called - even if you were to modify the string metatable to alter `__eq`.

Strings in Lua are always interned, so this comparison will always run in constant time. Since it is a primitive comparison, it can't possibly throw an error. No metamethod is called.

There is nothing to protect from: No possible performance issue / DoS vulnerability, no possible fancy side effects or code execution, no possible error.

(*Highly theoretically:* If a debug hook running every *n* instructions is registered, it might fire as the comparison is executed. You can hardly "protect" against a debug hook though.)

Comment: What if I were to put each of my strings in a table and have a second table to validate each string, then compare each table and prevent the metamethod from being tampered with? And ofc use obfuscation to make it more difficult.

Comment: What if I convert a string to a table compare the tables using __eq then if they match revert the tables back to strings. Use Lua obfuscation to make modifications difficult, but still possible. @LMD

Comment: @Blurryman sorry what?

Comment: I've updated my question with some code, about my previous comments on your answer.

Answer (score 0):

But it makes sense, for example a check against the Length.
A check against the Content seems also possible but need more lines.
And i like one liner in Lua Standalone to show...

```
> _VERSION
Lua 5.4
> eqtab = setmetatable({"Test1", "Test2"}, {__eq = function(left, right) print('SIMON SAYS:') return(#left == #right) end})
> eqtab == {1}
SIMON SAYS:
false
> eqtab == {}
SIMON SAYS:
false
> eqtab == {"Test1", "Test2"}
SIMON SAYS:
true
> eqtab == {1, 2}
SIMON SAYS:
true
```